# Run a script from a link

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have the following script that shows me information in a div, it works very well but with a button ... I am trying to make it walk from a link, I tried many ways and nothing, any ideas?

```
<script>
function showCustomer(str) {

  var xhttp;    
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "getcustomer.php?q="+str, true);
  history.pushState(null, "", str+ ".xhttp");
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

<input type='button' value='6df67913c1' onclick='showCustomer(this.value);' />
```

Comment: What do you mean by a link? Do you mean using the <a> tag?

Comment: Yes, I am using the XD translator, I want to use the <a> tag

Comment: Preferred way is to use an event listener instead of the inline `onClick()`. If you use jquery, you could attach to a class or id, and preventDefault action.

Comment: You could just set your anchor tag `href` to a hash `<a href="">6df67913c1</a> Or maybe add `event.preventDefault();` into your `showCustomer()` function... Please give an example of your current attempt with the **link** > anchor tag `<a>`

Comment: @TimMorton Great suggestion but I don't think something as simple as this would be worth loading in the `jQuery` library. This can be done in pure `javascript` and little of it.

Comment: This appears to be a javascript problem, not PHP. Please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: I have tried more variants than these three and nothing works, I admit that I am just starting and little I understand javascript
<a href='' onclick='javascript:showCustomer(6df67913c1);'>click me</a>
<a href='' onclick='showCustomer(6df67913c1);'>click me</a>
<a href=''>6df67913c1</a>
My concern is to have to modify the script, it would be difficult for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

```
    <script>
        function showCustomer(element) {
          const str = element.getAttribute('data-value')
          var xhttp;    
          if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = "";
            return;
          }
          xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
              document.getElementById("contenido").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            }
          };
          xhttp.open("GET", "getcustomer.php?q="+str, true);
          history.pushState(null, "", str+ ".xhttp");
          xhttp.send();
        }
    </script>
    <a href="#" onclick="showCustomer(this)" data-value="6df67913c1">Same, from link</a>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, I would never have done it without help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do something like this

```js
const myLinkButton = document.getElementById('my-Link-button')
  ;
myLinkButton.onclick=e=>
  { 
  e.preventDefault()  // -> disable link action for new url
  console.log( myLinkButton.dataset.value )
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" data-value="6df67913c1" id="my-Link-button" >button by link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `<a href="JavaScript: void (0)" onclick="callYourFunction()>link<\a>`